# iOS: get all message of push notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

In my app I have push notification and it work fine.

In this method:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

     NSLog(@"message:%@", userInfo);
}
```

I can get the message of my last notification.

But the problem is that this method is called only when I tap on my alert/banner notification when app is in background mode. And it give me only the last message. When app is in background I want to save all message, is there a way to do it?

**EDIT:** I use Parse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No is not the right way to use push notification.

When you receive a *push notification*, you in any case should request to your server informations. For example new messages and info around them.

I created a *social network* in this way and if you see *whatsapp* for example, you receive also 10 push notification, then when you launch whatsapp it receives all messages...**but if there isn't connection, it doesn't receive new messages because are not previously stored from push notification!**

**Push notification is just for the device and for advise the app that need to do something.**